# NextJS dynamic routing with modal reload causing overlay background to disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a very simple NextJS app where opening a page will update the URL but won't trigger a navigation and will instead display the content inside a modal. The URL still reflects the actual page location and any refresh brings the user there.

When the modal open, I want to still keep the original content off the page faded in the background and the modal should come to the front.

Right now when my modal opens, the original background content disappears rather than faded in the background.

I've replicated the issue in code-sandbox : `https://codesandbox.io/s/replicating-backdrop-disappearing-rqt21?file=/pages/index.js`

In the code-sandbox example, when you click the login button, you will see the modal works but the original background disappears. How can I get the background content to just be faded.

Please help.

Comment: That's because you're navigating to a new `login` page when pressing the `Login` link. Your code is triggering a navigation.

Comment: @juliomalves Is there a way to avoid that so I'm not triggering navigation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats), what you're attempting to do is not possible/practical. You can't simultaneously keep a page loaded while loading another page. If you want to keep the same page loaded, then you'll have to utilize [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) with [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing), which I feel is overkill for static authentication pages.

Instead, you should either create a `Layout` component that wraps over the entire app (using [_app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)) or selectively wrap each route with a reusable layout component.

On a side note, I'd recommend avoiding importing the same 3rd party global CSS more than once. If you're importing it more than once, it's a sign that you most likely should be using Next's custom app page for [global stylesheets](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules) (not required, but should eliminate redundant stylesheet imports).

Demo:

[image: Edit NextJS Layout]

---

**components/Layout/index.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href="/">
        <a className="link">Home</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/login">
        <a className="link">Login</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/signup">
        <a className="link">Signup</a>
      </Link>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Itaque eos id
        agere, ut a se dolores, morbos, debilitates repellant. Duo Reges:
        constructio interrete. Qualis ista philosophia est, quae non interitum
        afferat pravitatis, sed sit contenta mediocritate vitiorum? Vide ne ista
        sint Manliana vestra aut maiora etiam, si imperes quod facere non
        possim. <i>Quid censes in Latino fore?</i> Ita relinquet duas, de quibus
        etiam atque etiam consideret. <i>Quippe: habes enim a rhetoribus;</i>{" "}
        <b>Sum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset.</b>{" "}
      </p>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}

/* eslint-enable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
```

**pages/_app.js**

```
import "react-responsive-modal/styles.css";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import "../styles.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

**pages/index.js**

```js
export default function IndexPage() {
  return <h1>Index Page</h1>;
}
```

**pages/login.js**

```js
import Router from "next/router";
import { Modal } from "react-responsive-modal";

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <Modal center blockScroll open onClose={() => Router.push("/")}>
      <p>Login</p>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

**pages/signup.js**

```js
import Router from "next/router";
import { Modal } from "react-responsive-modal";

export default function SignupPage() {
  return (
    <Modal center blockScroll open onClose={() => Router.push("/")}>
      <p>Signup</p>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Comment: The above solution kind of works. However there is one slight issue. When the modal opens, it does not keep the original content (i.e. the current page your are on) on the page and is not faded in the background. It direct the user to the new location. I've tried shallow routing but no luck e.g. `router.push("/login", undefined, undefined, {shallow: true})`

Comment: What you want isn't possible. You can't keep two separate pages loaded at the same time. You have two options: 1.) Separate the pages and use a universal wrapper layout (shown above) or 2.) Just spawn a modal over the current page while using a wrapper layout (the login page won't be SEO). A good example of option 2 is `twitch.tv`. A modal spawns over the current page, but a `/login` page doesn't exist.

Comment: In short, the purpose of shallow routing is to avoid triggering one of Nextjs' life cycle data fetching methods while updating the URL to the **same page**. An example would be navigating to `stackoverflow.com/questions/66145858` which shallow redirects to `stackoverflow.com/questions/66145858/nextjs-dynamic-routing-with-modal-reload-causing-overlay-background-to-disappear`. Since you're staying on the same page (for example: `pages/questions/[...slug].js`) but only changing the URL, a shallow redirect is necessary; otherwise, you'll be fetching the same data twice.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you are triggering a navigation since your link points to a different page.

To achieve your desired behaviour you could use query params within the same page in conjunction with [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing).

```js
export default function IndexPage() {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <div>
            <Link href="/?login=true" as="/login" shallow={true}>
                <a>Login</a>
            </Link>
            <Modal
                center
                blockScroll={true}
                open={!!router.query.login}
                onClose={() => router.push('/', undefined, { shallow: true })}
            >
                <p>Hello World!</p>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I know query param work but for SEO purposes I need to use `paths` rather than query param

Comment: Well, you could use `as="/login"` in the `Link`, but a refresh from there would take you to `login` page instead. Can't think of any other solution to that since `login` is its own page too.