# Next js modal with dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm trying to create a modal using nextjs following this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-route-as-modal
What I want is, when I go to the modal with dynamic routing, it will open over the page i'm already on, and if the user refresh the page or access it with an link, it should open the main page with the modal already open, how can i achieve that with next?

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145858/nextjs-dynamic-routing-with-modal-reload-causing-overlay-background-to-disappear)